# How can I restore a single app to my iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, sync, ipod-touch

When I recently upgraded my iPod Touch to iOS 4.1, I had to re-sync all my apps and music. The thing is only about half of my apps synced successfully. I wasn't completely devastated and just downloaded the ones that really wanted again. There is one app that I'd really like back, but I will have to pay for it again.

Is there a way to just re-sync a single app back to my iPod? It is a game and has all my saved data on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made the purchase from the same iTunes account, you wont have to make the purchase again. When you add the application, you will get a pop-up asking if you want to buy. When you click yes, another pop-up tells you that you have already purchased the app and asks if you want to download it again.

Comment: Haha, didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've already downloaded it, you won't have to pay for it. If it's there in iTunes, just goto your device page, applications and just select the app you want to sync.